# rust performance in IDE and command line

Tags: rust

I am a beginner of rust. I wrote a project with one main.rs and two module files. The dev environment is CLion+Intellij Rust plugin on MacOS 11.1. The program is a simple CPU-intensive computation task. To measure its performance, I used following method:

```
    let timer = Instant::now();
    task();  // the main function of the task
    println!("{:.2?}", timer.elapsed());
```

When I ran the program in CLion's IDE, it prints a running duration of like 500~700µs.

However, if I ran the program (~project/target/debug/project) from command line in Mac Terminal, it prints 3~7ms. That's a difference one magnitude, which really confused me.

How to explain this difference? And any advice to improve the performance in command line? Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Is it possible CLion's IDE is running a release build? If you make a release build and run it from the command line, what is the performance?

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger. I assume CLion is running this debug version as well, because its output reads `Running \`target/debug/project\``.

Comment: I think I got the answer. I have misstated the problem. I was not running the program in MacOS's terminal actually, but in CLion's Terminal window, which I thought it is equivalent to the OS's terminal. If I run the debug version in real OS's terminal, it prints same performance (500~700µs). And I also tried a release version as you and @palako advised, it prints like 20~40µs. This is what I expected. Thanks for your comments and advices.

Comment: @Cuteufo, you probably should to post your findings as an answer, it can be useful for other CLion users.

Answer (score 0):

run

> $cargo build --release

and execute the binary that will be created in

> ~project/target/release/project

and compare with that instead.

Also, assuming that you're doing this already, but make sure to measure things many times and average the results; your computer is doing a whole lot of other things at the same time, and one task could be interrupted at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer. I have misstated the problem. I was not running the program in MacOS's terminal actually, but in CLion's Terminal window, which I thought it is equivalent to the OS's terminal - but it turns out to be not now. If I run the debug version in real OS's terminal, it prints same performance (500~700µs). And I also tried a release version, it prints like 20~40µs. This is what I expected.